# SSRS Calculations with multiple datasets

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a report with 3 datasets. Each dataset is pulling data from a different data warehouse. At the end of my report, I have a table that is getting the totals from each dataset, and I have successfully done this for normal total fields. However, there are some fields that are percentages. Below is an example of the expression I have in my text box.

I am taking the existing expression from the table with one dataset and trying to add the value from each data set so I can get a total percentage.

**Field using 1 dataset**

```
=code.SafeDividePercent(Sum(Fields!Field1.Value), Sum(Fields!Field2.Value))
```

**Field combining all data sets**

```
=code.SafeDividePercent(
Sum(Fields!Field1.Value, "DataSet1") + 
Sum(Fields!Field1.Value, "DataSet2") + 
Sum(Fields!Field1.Value, "DataSet3")
), 
(
Sum(Fields!Field2.Value, "DataSet1") + 
Sum(Fields!Field2.Value, "DataSet2") + 
Sum(Fields!Field2.Value, "DataSet3")
)
```

However, when I try this I get the following error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=code.SafeDividePercent(
Sum(Fields!Field1.Value, "DataSet1") + 
Sum(Fields!Field1.Value, "DataSet2") + 
Sum(Fields!Field1.Value, "DataSet3")
, 
Sum(Fields!Field2.Value, "DataSet1") + 
Sum(Fields!Field2.Value, "DataSet2") + 
Sum(Fields!Field2.Value, "DataSet3")
)
```

You just had brackets in the wrong place I think.

Comment: Thank you @alanschofield that has fixed my issue!

I have another field which is very similar but is using a CLng function and I am getting a an error with this as well.

=Code.SafeDivideVariance(
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value, "Dataset1")) +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value, "Dataset2")) + 
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field1.Value, "Dataset3"))
, 
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value, "Dataset1")) +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value, "Dataset2")) +
Sum(CLng(Fields!Field2.Value, "Dataset3"))
)

Comment: Glad you got it working. As for the next issue.... You need to start a new question. When you do, make sure you include any custom code such as your SafeDivideVariance function. I'm sure somebody will be able to help.